# C Programming, Variables

Tags: c++

When we declare variables in a class and then when we assign the value of those variables, for example like this

```
class c {

    public :

    int x;
    int x2;

    c () {
        x = 0;
        x2 = 0;

        scanf ("%d", &x); and now we're gonna input for example 10
    } 
};
```

each time the class is used, I mean each time the constructor is called, the value of x becomes 0 again since it is initialized as zero in the constructor. However if we don't initialize the value, there will be errors.

My question is that how can we keep the value of the variable when we call the constructor again and again so that it doesn't become zero ?

Edit:

```
void example () {

int i;
scanf ("%d", &i); 
switch (i) {
case 1 : {Object ob1; system ("cls"); menu ();} // this object contains a value like 20 
case 2 : {Object ob2; system ("cls"); menu ();} 
}  

}
```

There is another switch case in Object 1 which includes an option to go back to a main menu, now if I enter 1 again go back to object 1 I cannot see the value 20, it will be 0

Comment: 1) This is C++, not C 2) This program will not compile; comments should be preceded by // 3) The constructor gets called when you create a new object, if you need to perform the same actions repeatedly just create a new method and call that

Comment: Each instance of the class has its own variable, so technically you are not reseting the value to 0.

Comment: I know, it is an example ,

Comment: Let's say you call the constructor again then the value becomes zero

Comment: You shouldn't call the constructor again. Could you please edit your code with something to explain what you are doing to create an object of class c, and how you expect this to work - these two pieces are critical in understanding the X of your XY question (you ask how to do Y, so that you can solve X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you understand the difference between classes and objects/instances? Classes are merely a "Cookie-cutter" for objects. You don't "call" a constructor as such, but you create an instance of your class (which implicitely calls the constructor):

```
c myObj; 
c anotherObj;
```

This code will create two *instances* of class c, both with their own version of x1 and x2. It's true that the constructor is run a second time when creating `anotherObj`, but it operates on totally different memory. So the values of x1 and x2 in `myObj` won't be touched.

**Edit:** The point of class member functions is that they operate on an implicit additional parameter named this. You could imagine that the "constructor call" actually looks like that (Just for illustrative purposes, not meant to be valid code):

```
c* this = malloc(sizeof(c));
constructor(c);
// With "constructor" actually being:

void ctor(c* this) {
    this->x1 = 0;
    this->x2 = 0;
    // ..
}
```

That can also be achieved in C - but in C++, it happens implicitly, without you having to write code like this. You just write `c newObj;` or `c* obj = new c;`.

Apart from that: Member variables should be privat, and your mixing C library code (`scanf`) with C++ classes - use `iostreams` for input/output in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is called only once for each instance so need to worry about that. You will never reset the value of x for a given instance to 0 because of its constructor.

Comment: for example : we call the constructor c and then we call constructor d and then c again. Now I don't want to get reset values.

Comment: @NeptuneX you **can't** call constructor c and then d and then c again. Only a **single** constructor is called for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a static variable. Then read the value of x from that static variable.

Comment: But isn't that exactly what he doesn't want to have?